# Copy gradient or style from photoshop to illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient

I am new to illustrator, if this is too basic do provide links for me (tutorial).
I've made a shape, and I put styles on the layer, gradient, color overlay, opacity reduced, I know how to copy the shape, but to get the exact same gradient, opacity, how to do it? it's like a blend of styles.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to transfer Layer Style settings directly from Photoshop to Illustrator.

The best you can do is make note of the settings in Photoshop, then recreate the appearance settings in Illustrator.

Comment: I can do that to all of the effect?

Comment: It depends on what **exactly** is involved in the layer style. You didn't really provide a detailed description. Illustrator does have gradients, strokes, drop shadows, glows, etc. But there are some items, such as Bevel & Emboss which are not as easily created with Illustrator.

Comment: okay let say gradients, how to remake them? where can I see the setting in photoshop and how to remake them in illustrator.

Comment: See the settings in Photoshop via the Layer Styles.. simply make note of the colors you used and the options you used. Then to apply a gradient in Illustrator select an object and use the Gradient panel to try and mimic your Layer style settings.

Comment: well I am a noob, I mean I need to know, where to see the gradient settings so I can make a note, (I used ready made gradients) and where I can put it in the illustrator, sorry to keep troubling you

Comment: Double-click the Gradient Overlay in the Layers Panel of Photoshop. Then click directly on the little gradient bar you see in the Layer Styles Dialog. Honestly these are very basic items and you may be better off starting with some rudimentary tutorials regarding the tools in both Photoshop and Illustrator.